# Difference between "to summarize" and "to recap"

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

> recap: state again as a summary; recapitulate: *a way of recapping the story so far* | [ no obj. ] : *to recap, it’s been a year full of ups and downs.* — NOAD

Is there any difference between "to sum up", "to summarize", and "to recap"?

Comment: I am slightly troubled by your definition of 'recapitulate' as 'a way of recapping the story so far'. What is 'recap' and hence 'recapping' if not abbreviations of 'recapitulate'. So you appear to be defining a word in terms of its shortened abbreviations!

Comment: It was copied from the built-in dictionary of Mac. I think "a way of recapping the story so far" is an example for the usage of "recap", rather than a definition.

Comment: I am voting to close this question. The OP has done no research. The OP has used one definition in one dictionary as the basis for the question.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable (and not easily answered) question. It was asked ten years ago, when site standards were somewhat less stringent with regard to "show research" requirements, and it has drawn almost 9,000 visits over the years, suggesting that  there is some degree of long-term interest in the question it asks. With these considerations in mind,  I recommend leaving the question open.

Comment: @Greybeard "Questions that can be easily answered by consulting a reputable online dictionary should be closed with this reason unless the question includes an explanation of why the dictionary wasn't helpful". This question can't be answered by the dictionary (which has very similar definitions for sum up/summarize); you're not applying the close reason correctly.

Comment: It shows the definition of one of the three words the OP is comparing, so I don't really get your point, @Laurel: comparing the three definitions on a website like dictionary.com gives sufficient distinction between the three. (And does "the dictionary" refer to any dictionary?)

Comment: @SvenYargs Are renewed policies no grounds for reviewing old posts here on ELU?

Comment: @Laurel The problems with a lot of posters are (i) they ask the question "what is the difference between X and Y?" and then quote the similarities given and not the differences. (ii) They also use different contexts for X and Y. (iii) They do not use multiple dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

You've answered your own question. A recap involves a repeat of what was said (in condensed form.)

However, a summary is just a quick, condensed version - no repetition implied. *Sum up* is a shorter way of saying *summarize*.

Comment: Agreed, but a *summary* may occur after a longer narration, before it or in lieu of it.

Answer (score 2):

Also, "summarize" sounds more formal. "Sum up" and "recap" are informal.

I would use "To summarize..." or "In summary..." in an academic paper, but I would be more likely to use "To sum up..." or "To recap..." in a blog post.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it raises the issue of formality of tone, which I think is a significant element in distinguishing between "summarize" and "recap." However, the answer would be stronger if you added a citation to a reference work that supports your contention (which I think is defensible).

Comment: "Recap" is definitely less formal (I associate it with TV reviews and live commentary blogs), I'm not so sure about "sum up": although there's often a belief that things with long words sound more elevated and sophisticated, many short words are perfectly fine in the most formal English.

Answer (score 0):

A review of dictionary definitions suggests that there is very little difference between *summarize* and *recap[itulate]* in core meaning. Here are the entries from some relevant terms from *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary*:

> **recap** *n* {by shortening} (ca. 1926) : RECAPITULATION
>
> **recap** *vb* (1945) : RECAPITULATE
>
> **recapitulate** *vt* (1556) **1 a :** to restate briefly : SUMMARIZE **b :** to give new form or expression to **2 :** to repeat the principle stages or phases of  **~** *vi* : SUM UP
>
> **summarize** *vt* (1871) : to tell in or reduce to a summary  **~** *vi* to make a summary
>
> **summary** *n* (1509) : an abstract, abridgement, or compendium esp. of a preceding discourse
>
> **sum up** *vt* (15c) **1 :** to be the sum of : bring to a total <10 victories *summed up* his record> **2 a :** to present or show succinctly : SUMMARIZE <*sum up* the evidence presented> **b :** to assess and then describe briefly : size up **~** *vi* : to present a summary or recapitulation

So, to summarize/recapitulate/recap/sum up, in at least some meanings, *recap* = *recapitulate* = *summarize* **or** *sum up*, and *sum up* = *summarize*. According to the *Eleventh Collegiate*, all four of these words or phrases can be used to mean "to tell in or reduce to a summary."

In terms of age, *sum up* (in the sense of "add up") dates to the 1400s, *summary* (as a noun) to 1509, *recapitulate* to 1556, *summarize* to 1871, *recap* (as a noun) to 1926, and *recap* (as a verb) to 1945. MW doesn't specify when *sum up* began to be used in the sense of "summarize," but the OED finds examples of *sum* (without *up*) used in the sense of "summarize" from as early as 1621 and examples of *sum up* in the same sense from as early as 1692.

A fairly large group of similar terms exist in English to describe what S.I. Hayakawa, *Modern Guide to Synonyms and Related Words* (1968) calls "a short description of the main points of a longer work or presentation." These include the words *abridgment*, *abstract*, *digest*, *epitome*, *outline*, *précis*, *recap*, *recapitulation*, *summary*, *summing up*, and *synopsis*. Unfortunately, although he devotes more than a page to discussing the fione points of how seven of these terms differ, recap and recapitulation are not among them. Of summary, he writes:

> **Summary** is the most general of these words, referring to any attempt to condense into as few words as possible an extended train of thought: a day-to-day *summary* of the proceedings in the murder trial; concluding each chapter with a *summary* of its main arguments. The word implies a pithy paraphrase, with no attempt to catch the style of the original. Also, the word almost exclusively refers to something that follows after and is based on the extended presentation, or even concludes it—as suggested by the common phrase in speechmaking: in *summary*.

It seems to me that most of this description would apply equally well to *recap* used as noun and to the phrase "to recap" used in place of "in summary" in speechmaking.

I run into *recap* most often on news broadcasts (where, in the US, "a recap of today's news stories" corresponds to the BBC's familiar "and now for the main points") and in sports broadcasts (where postgame shows commonly feature "a recap of the game, consisting of rebroadcast snippets of key plays tied together with new commentary). As a side note, when I lived in Alberta for a couple of years in the very early 1970s, I was struck by the fact that the announcers of Calgary Stampeder football games referred to their impending recap of game highlights as "a résumé of the game."

My sense is that *summarize*, *sum up*, and *recap* have considerable overlap in meaning and that within that area of overlap the main difference is one of tone rather than content. *Recap* is a truncated form of the venerable verb *recapitulate*, which is not much used in everyday conversation by the people I hang around with; although *recap* as a noun may well be a century old and as a verb is not much younger, it may still come across to some audiences as somewhat less formal than *summarize*, and it almost certainly will seem less formal than *recapitulate*.

*Sum up* is interesting in that it appeared in English in a mathematical sense long ago but subsequently emerged from a standalone usage of *sum* that looks a lot like a truncation of summarize—except that *summarize* isn't recorded (by MW) until almost 200 years after the first instance that the OED reports of *sum up* in the relevant sense. I don't see a huge difference in tone between *sum up* and *summarize*, but others may have a different impression of their relative formality. I haven't been able to find a reference work that discusses this issue.